# Meteor js as front end, what use for backend?

Tags: meteor, backend

I would like to ask about best practiecs in creation of backend to Meteor.

I use Meteor js as Front End, and I am planning to use bunch of apache/php/yii framework/YiiMongoDbSuite at another port as backend(admin panel).

Maybe someone advices me the best practive for easy creation of admin part of meteor application?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you've already built your backend in PHP/Rails,etc you could consider a DDP client or REST to relay messages between meteor and the backend. [DDP](http://meteor.com/blog/2012/03/21/introducing-ddp) has a couple of advantages over REST

its an open connection you could even get down live updates.

Im not sure of any DDP clients for PHP yet though. There are a handful:

- Nodejs (https://github.com/oortcloud/node-ddp-client)
- .NET (https://github.com/sonyarouje/DDPClient.NET)
- Ruby (https://github.com/tmeasday/ruby-ddp-client)
- Python (https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/master/examples/unfinished/python-ddp-client)

You could use [REST](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router) to communicate too, but you would be missing out on a lot of functionality. With DDP you could access `Meteor.methods` and make subscriptions quite easily.

Finally, you could just connect straight to your mongodb and put your changes in. Meteor will handle them within 10 seconds.

*But* why not use Meteor itself as a backend? Using a seperat Meteor instance might make your admin area more secure. With Meteor as a backend, it would be far easier to maintain, you'd have compatible code to share between the two. You could use [Meteor.connect](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_connect) to access the client instance.

If your motivation is security you could just do this. There's almost no benefit of using a separate language and stack when Meteor already makes it so easy.

**UPDATE** : Meteor 0.7.0 introduced oplog tailing so you wouldn't have to wait 10 seconds for the updates to appear anymore. They would be instant as if from meteor itself.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I decited to build backend on Yii, because it gives you CRUD operations from the box and it is fast in development. DDP links are very helpfull. Little delay in 10 seconds is not critical.

Comment: I changed decision, now I am writing backend on Meteor. Thanks

Comment: yes Meteor is a full stack framework--it runs on both the client and the server. It makes little sense to me to use meteor only on the front-end.

Comment: I wrote a grunt script that makes it easy to decouple meteor from its backend and serve it statically. http://frozeman.de/blog/2013/08/using-meteor-as-frontend-library/

Answer (score 0):

Meteor listens to the MongoDB database directly, so any changes there will automatically update the application. This means that if you want to write to MongoDB from PHP you can, and then meteor will automatically detect changes and update the font end.

I believe this also will work with [numtel's meteor mysql package](https://github.com/numtel/meteor-mysql). This makes it super easy if you want to start using meteor for your components that need to update in real time or slowly migrate over a project.

We're currently trying this out for our real time notification systems. I thought we would have to learn to use DDP but really it's as easy as having both systems listening to the same DB.